# Loading new paths from each line on a text file with eval dont update $PATH variable on bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

Having to set a lot of paths on $PATH then wrote this code to load it from a text file:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd ~
  echo '#++++++' >> ./pathlstbkp
  cat ./pathlst >> ./pathlstbkp
  while read pth; do 
    cmd='export PATH="'$pth':$PATH"'
    eval ${cmd}
  done < ./pathlst
  echo '' > ./pathlst
```

As you can see [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442218/337382) when using eval the evaluated command doesnt run on subshell.
But it dont change the $PATH variable.
Now realized someting strange happens, it dont work on my test Ubuntu-LTS18-Minimal-X64 but works on my main machine, a Debian9.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster fixed the problem by reinstallation, so it's unlikely that the reason for the issue will ever be found.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the virtual machine and did the same again and it works, probably was something on evironment